# getting TypeError: o is not a function on a laravel and vue 2.6.14 project

Tags: vue.js

I get typeError: o is not a function when i run `npm run prod` but when i run `npm run dev` i don't get it

[image: TypeError: o is not a function]

it happens on both live server and development

my vue code

````
export default {
  name: "CreateTimesheet",
  props: ["employees", "creatorId"],
  mounted() {
    this.employee_id = this.creatorId;
    this.getProjects();
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      employee_id: 1,
      project_id: 0,
      projects_dropdown: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getProjects() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/getclientprojects/'+this.employee_id).then(response => response.json());
        this.projects_dropdown.push(...res.projects)
        this.project_id = res.active_projects // It happens when i add this line
      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>```
````

Comment: The error is at line 1 of your app.js file, maybe you have an error in there.  Post the contents in your question

Comment: @audiojames the app.js that it is mentioning in the error is the compiled 1 that has been minified do you mean the content of that 1

Comment: There does not appear to be anything in your vue component that would cause this error, so perhaps the error is in another file or package.

Comment: I am also suspecting that it's another package and if that's the case i just need to figure out which package it is

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when building my Vue project with version `^2.7.14`. I resolved it by downgrading to version `2.6.10` as follows:

```bash
npm i --save vue@2.6.10
npm i --save-dev vue-template-compiler@2.6.10
```

I needed to ensure that the `vue-template-compiler` version matches the Vue version.